# Llamar un procedimiento Almacenado de Insertar Registros

Tags: c#, sql-server

Tengo un procedimiento almacenado que me inserta registros en dos tablas al mismo tiempo. Y quiero que en el programa, cuando dé clic en el  botón de ***GUARDAR*** mande llamar a ese procedimiento. ¿Cómo puedo hacer ese proceso? 
De antemano muchas gracias.

Aquí esta mi SP:

```
create proc InserTablas 
(@Id_Pago char(10), @Pago decimal(12, 2), @Id_Capital char (10), @id_Pago2 char(10), @Fecha_Pago varchar(20))
AS
    INSERT INTO Pagos (id_pago, pago, id_capital) VALUES (@Id_Pago, @Pago, @Id_Capital);
    INSERT INTO detalle_pago (id_pago, fecha_pago) VALUES (@id_Pago2, @Fecha_Pago)
GO
```

Estoy trabajando con Visual Studio 2013 - C#

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado del lado de la aplicación (`C#`)? Necesitamos saber en dónde tienes problemas para ayudarte a solucionar, [no estamos para hacer tu tarea](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2878). Por favor incluye lo que has intentado :D

Answer (score 0):

```
     using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cadenaConexión))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InserTablas", con))
                    {
                        //Le indicas al SqlCommando que lo que va a ejecutar es Tipo Procedimiento Almacenado
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        //Aquí agregas los parámetros de tu procedimiento
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Pago", SqlDbType.Decimal.Value = Decimal.Parse(Pago.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Prameter2", SqlDbType.TipoDato.Value = Parameter2;
                        //Abres la conexión 
                        con.Open();
                        //Ejecutas el procedimiento, y guardas en una variable tipo int el número de lineas afectadas en las tablas que se insertaron
//(ExecuteNonQuery devuelve un valor entero, en éste caso, devolverá el número de filas afectadas después del insert, si es mayor a > 0, entonces el insert se hizo con éxito)
                        int numero = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: En general se trata de esperar a que el usuario aclare su escenario completo y muestre que intento para saber donde esta el problema. Fijate que si usa EF, este metodo no le sirve. Mas alla de eso, hacer open de la conexion no tiene sentido, ya que el command la va a abrir por defecto (y llegado el caso, si hacemos open, porque no hacer close tambien?)

Comment: Tienes razón, no indicó si usa EF ni dio más detalle, quise hacerle un ejemplo sencillo. Tengo entendido que cuando se ejecuta el código dentro del bloque 'using', cuando sale de éste, no es necesario cerrar la conexión, pues sea exitoso o no el proceso, la conexión se cerrará ;)

Comment: Justamente por eso lo decia.. tampoco es necesaria abrirla ;). O si la vas a abrir, coherentemente, cierrala ;).

Comment: No sabía que no era necesario abrir conexión con el command, siempre me guíe por los ejemplos de Microsoft, gracias por el dato, diario se aprende algo nuevo ;), de igual manera el ejemplo le servirá, porque ahora que veo los detalles en su pregunta, no hay etiqueta de EF, si le sirve, que lo tome.